# How to pass json string in alarmofire post api

Tags: swift, api, alamofire

I tried to make dictionary and passed params in post body:

[image].

```
**var arrDict = [Dictionary<String,Any>]()
var dict = Dictionary<String,Any>()
dict["section"] = "story"
dict["media"] = media
dict["media_time"] = "0"
dict["mime_type"] = "image/jpeg"
dict["media_type"] = "Image"
dict["height"] = self.arrImage[0].asset.pixelHeight
dict["width"] = self.arrImage[0].asset.pixelWidth
arrDict.append(dict)
print(arrDict)
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrDict, options: []) {
     if let content = String(data: json, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                  self.addStory(dic: content)

        }
 }**
```

Comment: what error are you getting with this code?

Comment: try passing `prettyPrinted` in `options`

Comment: You have not provided enough information for anyone to debug your code. You should give some indication of what the issue is that you're running into and some more detail re: how you're making the POST request.